# about ODE . Please help me anybody

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

It's about ODE question.

I cant understand about the question below.

$$y^2+(y')^2=1,\quad y(0)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$

How can I find $y$?

Comment: Express $y'$ as a function of $y$. Note that you obtain a separable ODE and integrate.

Comment: You have $\left(y'\right)^2=1-y^2$, thus $y'=\pm\sqrt{1-y^2}$. Solve each case as a separable equation.

Answer (score 1):

Differentiating gives $2y'\left(y+y''\right)=0$. If $y'=0$ then $y$ is constant, viz. $y=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$. Hereafter we suppose $y'\neq 0$ so $y''=-y$ and $y=y_0 \cos t + y'_0 \sin t$. Since $y_0 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$, $y'_0=\pm y_0$ so $y=\cos \left(t\mp \frac{\pi}{4}\right)$.

Answer (score 0):

You could also argue that one can substitute $$y=\sin(u(t)),\  y'=\cos(u(t))$$ because of the differential equation and then also $$y'=\frac{d}{dt}y=\cos(u(t))u'(t)$$ which tells us by comparing the expressions that $u'=1$, $ y(t)=\sin(t+C)$, $2^{-1/2}=y(0)=\sin(C)$ so that $C=\frac\pi4$ or $C=\frac{3\pi}4$.